# How do I move CS:GO installation from my Ubuntu (16.04) desktop to my freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 laptop?

Tags: games, steam

Is it possible to transfer my installation of Counterstrike Global Offensive in Steam on my Ubuntu on my desktop PC to my newly-installed Ubuntu system on my laptop? I've heard that other users have used the "Backup Local Content" feature on Steam on Windows to do what I want to do on their systems, however, would it be possible to do the same on Linux, and how exactly?

Comment: It works exactly as it does in Windows. I'm sure the exact steps can be found at Steam Community.